# How to loop through all items in the Magento cart?

Tags: php, magento

Okay, I have no idea how to do this simple thing. All I need is to loop through the 3 items that I have currently in the cart, so I can get item information about each one - like product category, item name, blah blah blah. I have googled this for an hour already, and have not found anything on what seems to be such a simple task. Getting quote, and then getAllItems() returns nothing for me. Anybody have any ideas / links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure getting the quote doesn't work?  The following code should work:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
    print_r($item->getData());
}
```

Of course, if you're not doing it from inside a Magento template/controller/model then you'll need to set up the environment appropriately:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

/* Then put your code here.. */
```

- Source: http://www.nicksays.co.uk/2009/02/testing-magento-modules/
- Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19020/#t99651

Comment: Yeah, strangely doesn't work for me. The page hangs for 10 seconds, then blanks out :(

Comment: Sometimes a `print_r` can go into an infinite recursion. Try something simple like `print $item->getName()`

Comment: If it's whiting out then it's likely a PHP memory issue, so checking your apache log and not using a potential memory heavy function such as `print_r`/`var_dump` as @powtac and @clockworkgeek suggest should be your next step.

Comment: Okay thank you guys/gals. We had a deadline issue with this one so I had to make it work another way (nothing to do with Magento). Will try to come back and figure this out on my own time, but since so many people agree that this is the right answer, it's probably just me personally having such a problem. Once again thanks for all the feedback.